# How can I schedule an update to be posted to my Facebook wall, at a certain time in the future?

Tags: facebook, scheduling

For example, I often write a blog post late at night, or during the weekend. If I mention it on Facebook as soon as I've written it, nobody will see it. I'd prefer to post it the following morning, when more people will be checking Facebook.

I presume there is no official feature for doing this, but it seems like it should be possible with an external service.

Comment: Officially Facebook provides this option.<br>
Please look into below link <br>
https://www.facebook.com/help/389849807718635/

Comment: Just FYI - When you try to do it from Profile it only gives you the option of posting to the PAST. Any future date gives you "Invalid Date You have specified a date in the future." error message. That's handy....not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [schedule-it](http://apps.facebook.com/schedule-it/). It's a Facebook app that lets you set the date and time of a wall post. You could also use it to schedule posts on a friend's wall.

Comment: **Does not work** anymore.  Error message: "This application does not yet support secure browsing (HTTPS)."

Answer (score 1):

Look at the bottom left corner of the status post box.  Type your post as usual, then click the small clock icon in the bottom left of the box to schedule the date/time you want the post to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Buffer](http://www.bufferapp.com). It can automatically scheduled social media posts at predefined schedules or custom time as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I built this.

Give [Publer](https://SuperPubler.com) a shot. It's a Superhero/App that lets you schedule your posts for your Facebook Profile (what you asked for), Pages, Groups and Events.

The free version lets you have up to 10 pending scheduled posts per each Account (Profile, Page, Group, Event). Once a pending scheduled post is published, you can schedule another one.

Answer (score 0):

The clock is no longer there on Facebook. Try [Post Planner](http://www.postplanner.com/). It is an app that allows you to schedule posts on Facebook whenever you want.

Answer (score -1):

There is a clock there but you cannot pick a date or time before the current time.
I guess it is used to determine where to place the post on your timeline.

Facebook help says that you can do this, however.

Answer (score -1):

If you create your post from your profile page (not your news feed) you will see a clock under the post once you start typing. As of Feb 18 2016 it appears you can schedule your post for a time later in the same day. It does not appear that you can schedule a post after the current day.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: This is for page not for profile. So it doesn't answer to the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "page" and what do you mean by "profile"? This works for my personal facebook account.

Comment: Then a screenshot would be helpful for us.

Comment: I see it now. You need to start the post by clicking in the "What's on your mind?" box when viewing your profile, _**not**_ your timeline. Unfortunately, even though you can choose a time later in the current day then now, if it's in the future you'll be prevented from saving the post.